# Git submodules commit

Tags: github

I have an android project thats has a submodule inside.Its all under GitHub.
I am making changes on the main as well as on the sumbmodule.
What is the best strategy to use?

1.Create a new branch (do I have to make a new branch on both the main as on the submodule )
2.Do changes.
3.Commit&Push.

I would like to commit all changes at the same time main and submodule.

Comment: Commit first in you submodule. Then commit in your project. The parent project stores the commit of the submodule, so if you pull the parent project in another directory, you will always game the same version of the submodule, even if there are new commits in the submodule. Until you commit the parent module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to ensure that each commit includes and expresses only single changes you've made, so if there aren't actual connections between the changes of both modules, **I suggest that you don't commit only once, but make multiple commits - at least twice - instead**.